# Sort dataframe by the year (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

So I have a dataframe with some values that are sorted via the dates on the left. How do I narrow it down to only the year 2020?

[image]

I have no clue what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering `Date` column is of `datetime type`.

If not, let's first convert it to `datetime`.

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

If we want to fetch only the records for year 2020.

```
df[df.Date.dt.year == 2020]
```

If we want to fetch all records from year 2020 and afterwards.

```
df[df.Date.dt.year >= 2020]
```

**Toy Example**

```
dt = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2021-05-01', freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':dt,
    'USD':np.arange(len(dt))
})
df

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date) ## Not required but fot the sake of eg

df[df.Date.dt.year == 2020]
## df[df.Date.dt.year >= 2020]
```

**Output**

```
    Date        USD
24  2020-01-31  24
25  2020-02-29  25
26  2020-03-31  26
27  2020-04-30  27
28  2020-05-31  28
29  2020-06-30  29
30  2020-07-31  30
31  2020-08-31  31
32  2020-09-30  32
33  2020-10-31  33
34  2020-11-30  34
35  2020-12-31  35
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just use a greater than or equal to the date I'm filtering, and use the date it returns.

Here is an example:

```
df[(df['Date'] >= '2020-1-1')]
```

Have a nice day!